# Iterate over a column list pandas with a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a list in a pandas dataframe:

```
0: [car, telephone]
1: [computer, beach, book, language]
2: [rice, bus, street]
```

Every list is in each row.Also, this list has different length in every row.
and I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {'car': 'transport',
'rice':'food'
'book':'reading'
}
```

After that I have flattened the dict

```
d = {val:key for key, lst in dict.items() for val in lst}
```

I would like to iterate over the all items in the list and create a column of this kind,

*this is the desired output*:

```
index col1  col2
    0: [car, telephone],transport
    1: [computer, beach, book, language], reading
    2: [rice, bus, street], food
```

I have tried:

```
  df['col2'] = data_df['col1'].index.map(d)
```

but I get

```
col2
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Never assign built-in function as a variable this overwrites them: `dict = {...}`

Comment: What is `lst` in your definition of `d`?

Comment: `lst` because my dictionary is a nested list, but I simplified in this example.

Comment: @Andreas I have edited the question with the desired output.

Comment: with what you have in the example, your mapping dictionary only has 3 items - one item for each of our rows. should the dictionary have all of the 9 different words that are in the row-lists? Does the map just need to find one word in the row-list, or should it match everything? Could it ever be the case that a row-list contains contradicting elements - like containing rice (food) and beach (reading)?

Comment: also, what are you trying to accomplish exactly with your dictionary-flattening step? When I run that, I can't much parse the result: `{'t': 'car', 'r': 'book', 'a': 'book', 'n': 'book', 's': 'car', 'p': 'car', 'o': 'rice', 'f': 'rice', 'd': 'book', 'e': 'book', 'i': 'book', 'g': 'book'}`

Answer (score 1):

You can `.explode` then use the dictionary for translation and then group again:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'col': {0: ['car', 'telephone'], 1: ['computer', 'beach', 'book', 'language'], 2: ['rice', 'bus', 'street']}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dct = {'car': 'transport', 'rice':'food', 'book':'reading'}
```

**Code:**

```
df2 = df.explode('col')
df2['col2'] = df2['col'].replace(dct)
df['col2'] = df2[~df2['col'].eq(df2['col2'])]['col2']
```

**Output:**

```
   id                                col       col2
0   1                   [car, telephone]  transport
1   2  [computer, beach, book, language]    reading
2   3                [rice, bus, street]       food
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` on a custom function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'col1': ['car', 'telephone']}, {'col1': ['computer', 'beach', 'book', 'language']}, {'col1': ['rice', 'bus', 'street']}])


def get_col2(lst):
    d={'car': 'transport','rice':'food','book':'reading'}
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k in lst:
            return v
        
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(get_col2)
```

Output:

|  | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ['car', 'telephone'] | transport |
| 1 | ['computer', 'beach', 'book', 'language'] | reading |
| 2 | ['rice', 'bus', 'street'] | food |